# CRM Access Team Plug-in

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement for sending an email when a user is added to an access team regarding an opportunity, but can't for the life of me get my plugin to attach to the right message. I have so far tried using:

Associate - None
AddMembers - Team
AddUserToRecordTeam - TeamTemplate

GrantAccess - Opportunity

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Users and Teams have an N:N relationship in Dynamics CRM. This means that there is an intermediary entity as shown below. The type for this entity can be found by going to Settings=>Customizations=>Customize The System=>Entities=>Team=>N:N Relationships=>teammembership_association. Here it can be seen that the relationship entity name in this case is "teammembership".

**Structure for N:N relationship:**
systemuser  N:1  teammembership  N:1  Team

Knowing this, I would try registering a plugin on create of teammembership.

Answer (score 1):

Access Teams have two messages:

- AddUserToRecordTeam - User is added to an Access Team
- RemoveUserFromRecordTeam - User is removed

`TeamTemplate` entity, Server-only

I suggest profiling and debugging to make sure your code isn't indeed firing but dong nothing.

[MSDN has a long list of all messages of all entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx)

AddMembers for Team won't work because that's for Owner Teams, not Access Teams.

GrantAccess won't work either because that's fired on Sharing.